# What does the term 'locally' mean exactly when used in software?

Tags: computer-science, local, terminology

What does the term locally mean? 
For example, "Can you run it locally" and "Can you login locally?" versus doing the same thing but on a Dev environment .

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a word definition. You should ask instead on EL&U instead of SO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The specifics depend on context, but the term generally implies action in the same location (machine, function, program, ...) as some other point of reference.  In particular,

- To log in locally to a machine typically means to sit at that machine's console and log in, as opposed to logging in remotely over the network.
- To log in locally to a web application, on the other hand, might mean to connect and log in from a machine on the same network as the web server, or it might mean more specifically connecting from the same machine.
- To run a program locally means to run it on the machine you are sitting at (or for a program to run it on the same machine it is running on itself), as opposed to causing it to run on some remote machine.

Answer (score 1):

Running on the same machine that you are currently on.

A 'local' database would be served from the same machine as the client software accessing it. Serving a website 'locally' would mean the webserver was on the same machine as the browser trying to access it.

Comment: Ahhh I see. So this is different from running something in a dev environment because you are using that environment's database for example. Correct?

Comment: Not necessarily - your dev environment could be local. My dev environment for building web apps is 'local'. I run the webserver and the database on my desktop machine, and test via the browser on the same machine. I never go out on the network to access any other machines.

Answer (score 0):

"Own your own computer" would probably be the best translation. So, not on a server or some other remote device. It does also not mean you have to setup a local server or something. For example; you can run a simple html file locally by just running it in a browser but in production you would probably have it served by a webserver instead.

Comment: How would this be different from trying to run something in a dev environment on your computer? Or are they the same thing then?

Comment: A dev environment is mostly the same thing. But a dev environment is mostly more setup to do actual development on the project. Running something locally does not necessarily need all the tools a developer needs to do it's development.

Comment: Ah makes sense! Thanks for your detailed explanation. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Deployment environment wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deployment_environment):

> Local: Developer's desktop/workstation

Answer (score 0):

It depends.   It means, "Can you run it where you are at without going over a network".  "Where you are at" can mean physically, or logically.

So if I opened my physical laptop, "log in locally" means "can I log in to the machine" (because it's locked).

If I have already have a session on my machine to another system, "log in locally" can mean "without needing to authorize myself over the network again".

Compare two terminal sessions:

```
localMachine> ssh -u user remoteMachine.com
password: XXXX
remoteMachine> connect to database test
```

and

```
localMachine> connect to database test at remoteMachine user foo using bar
```

The first example would be considered to be done "locally", the second "remotely".

Answer (score -1):

it certainly relates to being able to run a server at your local machine (like localhost, 127.0.0.1), search for like apache HTTP server to learn how to create a local web server in your machine